# how to encrypt data using BIO_SSL?

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am using BIO_SSL which is in bio.h to create SSL.
but how to encrypt data using BIO_SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid your question is akin to "I have a nail. How do I build a house?". However, perhaps the example on [this page](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_s_connect.html#) will get you started with openssl. Also, [this book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002701) is pretty good for understanding openssl.

EDIT:
If you are looking to encrypt data rather than do SSL, *and* you want to use BIO's, then consider the [`BIO_f_cipher()`](http://openssl.org/docs/crypto/BIO_f_cipher.html#) bio. I personally find the [EVP](http://openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_EncryptInit.html#) interface to be easier to understand than the BIO interface.

Comment: thnaks for ur reply.
i am able to create ssl and connected it using BIO.
but i am looking for inbuild api in bio.